# Sessions in Ruby not registering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Im having a problem with setting sessions

```
def item
    @username = session[:Username]
    @fsesh = params[:happy]
    @sksesh = params[:skyrim]
    if @username
      if @fsesh
      # redirect_to polymorphic_path(@Cart, :skyrim => params[:skyrim])
      # redirect_to :application => '/Cart', :skyrim => params[:skyrim]
        redirect_to '/Cart'
        session[:skyrim] = ""
        session[:happy] = @fsesh
      elsif @sksesh
        redirect_to '/Cart'
        session[:happy] = ""
        session[:skyrim] = @sksesh
      elsif @sksesh && @fsesh
        session[:skyrim] = @sksesh
        session[:happy] = @fsesh
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Please select an option"
        redirect_to '/Purchase'
      end
    else 
      flash[:notice] = "Please login"
      redirect_to '/Purchase'
    end
  end
```

basically when trying to register both parameters "elsif @sksesh && @fsesh" only the value for @fsesh is popping up.

Purchase page were parameters are set from

```
<div class="p-row bx-wrapper">
    <ul class="bx-holder bxslider">
        <li><img src="res/skyrim.jpg" name="sky" /></li>
        <li><img src="res/background.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="purchase-row grid-container">
        <form class="p-form " action="/item" method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="skyrim" value="sky">Check out this skyrim picture!<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="happy" value="happy">Check out this picture of a happy man!</a><br>
            <input class="pass-but" id="no1" type="submit" value="Add to cart" >
        </form>  
        <h5><%= flash[:notice] %></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cart page where the parameter values are shown

```
<div class="cart-row">    
    <div class="grid-container">
        <h1><%= session[:Username] %>'s Cart Page</h1>
        <form>
            <p><%= session[:happy] %></p><br>
            <p><%= session[:skyrim] %></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if this wasn't a challenging question I'm still new to html, css, jquery & RoR :D

Comment: because you have 'if @fsesh' before the elsif, the elsif can never be called since whenever `@sksesh && @fsesh` is true, `@fsesh` is true too.

Comment: btw, you do not need to add these to the session if all you want to do is to show the values in the next page. Check this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: there are better ways to go about this, but if you want the code to work, move `elsif @sksesh && @fseh` to be `if @sksesh && @fseh` and `if @fseh` to `elsif @fseh`